# Braintree sandbox: test refund (immediate settlement)

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment, braintree

I'm writing unit tests in PHP to test refunds. To do this, I make a charge, then pass the transaction ID to the refund method.

Obviously I cannot get the test to pass if the transaction is still settling. So I tried the `Braintree_TestHelper::settle($transactionId)` method. It turns out that that method is missing from /tests/TestHelper.php.

What alternative do I have now to settle the transaction immediately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

You are looking for the function [Braintree_Test_Transaction::settle()](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/php#settlement-status).